# SQL join one column with another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am creating a table and i have a field like NAME and i want to join this NAME with another table column name how can i do it??

```
 create table History_Table
(
  TempID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SV_templates(TemplateID),
  Name varchar(50) ????
  RunDate datetime,
  RunBy varchar(50)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select * 
from History_Table H
join another_table T
on H.Name=T.Name
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, think what data you want in the result. We have many options for that:

1. If you want data which are in both tables, then you can use `INNER JOIN`.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM History_Table AS A INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE AS B ON A.NAME = B.NAME
   ```
2. If you want all records of the first table, then you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM History_Table AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN OTHER_TABLE AS B ON A.NAME = B.NAME
   ```